# Returning foreach value from function to array

Tags: php

I have a function and I am passing array argument in it to validate it. Then on the next page I am inserting the array argument. As below:

```
function check_subject($sub_array)
{
    foreach($sub_array as $value)
    {
        if (!empty($value))
        {
            if (!preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]{2,20}$/', $value))
            {
        return "Not supported format";
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Other page I am inserting as `$errors[] = check_subject($g8_sub_vali);` and I am storing the return result in an $error[] array.

Than I am printing error if any else do somehitng as below..

```
if($errors)
        {
            foreach ($errors as $msg) 
            {
                if(!empty($msg))
                {
                echo " - $msg<br />\n";
                }
            }
        }
else
        {
            echo "There is no error";
                }
```

But I am not getting the else loop value that is "There is no error". I think there is a problem in returning from function. Can you please suggest me?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($errors)` before the `if($errors)`. What do you get?

Comment: Your function return a string. not an array! You assigned it to an array `$errors[]` It can accessible by `$errors[0]` in if condition.

Comment: var_dump gives array(1) { [0]=> NULL } if there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making:-

```
$errors[] = check_subject($g8_sub_vali);
```

This line would append a null to array even in case you are making a check for a valid entry because function would return null.

So if you want to prevent this you should do:-

```
$err = check_subject($g8_sub_vali);
if(empty($err)==false)
   $errors[] = $err;
```

This would give you a valid values of errors and you will get in else loop if there is no error.

Comment: @user2642907 It's not clean code so. The function `check_subject` always should return a value in this issue. not sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Return in this way

```
return(array("Not supported format"));
```

Comment: What's wrong with him returning a string? There is nothing wrong with assigning a string to an array element.

Comment: can you try now with print_r($errors) and let me know the result, also please let me know the INPUT you are trying...

Comment: By doing it your way he would end up with a nested array: $errors[] = array("Not supported format");

Comment: ohh yeah, he must do $errors = array("Not supported format");

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$errors = array();   
if($err = check_subject($g8_sub_vali)){
    $errors[] = $err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function check_subject($sub_array)
{
    $array = [];
    foreach($sub_array as $value){
        if (!preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]{2,20}$/', $value))
        {
            array_push($array, $value.' - Not supported format');
        }

    }
    return $array;
}
```

array_push will add the message to end of the array if value dont contain alpha numberic value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to show which subjects are not in supported format:

function:

```
function check_subject($sub_array) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($sub_array as $value) {
        if (!empty($value) && preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]{2,20}$/', $value)) {
            array_push($results, false);
        }
        else {
            array_push($results, true);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

continue:

```
$errors = check_subject($g8_sub_vali);

foreach ($errors as $key=>$error) {
    if ($error) {
        echo "error on subject number " . ($key+1);
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```